# Form connection with endpoint NextJS 13.2

Tags: javascript, forms, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to connect this form:

```
'use client'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

export const Formulario = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    Company: '',
    Position: '',
    Email: '',
    NumberOfEmployees: '',
    Terms: false,
    Message: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    const fieldValue = type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: fieldValue,
    }));
    console.log(`Field '${name}' updated to value: ${fieldValue}`);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Form data submitted:', formData);
    fetch('/api/SubmitForm', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Form submission response:', data.message); 
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Form submission error:', error);
        
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="row white-font p-3 d-flex">
      <div className="col-10 mx-auto">
        <h5 className="text-center">Únete a la lista de espera</h5>
      </div>
      <div className="col-10 mx-auto">
        <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group className="">
            <Form.Label className="formlabel" column="sm">
              Empresa
            </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              className="formplaceholder"
              size="sm"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Nombre de tu Company"
              name="Company"
              value={formData.Company}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group className="">
            <Form.Label className="formlabel" column="sm">
              Cargo
            </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              className="formplaceholder"
              size="sm"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Cargo actual en tu Company"
              name="Position"
              value={formData.Position}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group className="">
            <Form.Label className="formlabel" column="sm">
              Mail corporativo
            </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              className="formplaceholder"
              size="sm"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Mail de trabajo"
              name="Email"
              value={formData.Email}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group className="">
            <Form.Label className="formlabel" column="sm">
              Número de trabajadores en tu equipo
            </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              className="formplaceholder"
              size="sm"
              type="number"
              placeholder="¿Cuántos sois en tu equipo?"
              name="NumberOfEmployees"
              value={formData.NumberOfEmployees}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group className="" >
            <Form.Label className="formlabel" column="sm">
              Déjanos un mensaje
            </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              className="formplaceholder"
              size="sm"
              as="textarea"
              rows={3}
              placeholder="¿Tienes algo que decirnos? ¡Deja un comentario aquí!"
              name="Message"
              value={formData.Message}
              onChange={handleChange}
              spellCheck="false" // Update "spellcheck" to "spellCheck"
            />

          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group className="inline-checkbox p-1">
            <Form.Check
              required
              type="checkbox"
              name="Terms"
              onChange={handleChange}
              checked={formData.Terms}
              feedbackType="invalid"
              id="validationFormik0"
              className="formTerms"
            />
            <Form.Check.Label
              htmlFor="validationFormik0"
              data-bs-toggle="modal"
              data-bs-target="#ModalTerms"
              className="form-check-label formTerms p-1"
            >
              He leído y acepto la política de privacidad
            </Form.Check.Label>
          </Form.Group>

          <div className="d-grid gap-2">
            <Button className="Gradient-Button" size="sm" type="submit">
              ¡Quiero firmail!
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Formulario;
```

And this endpoint:

```
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(request, response) {
  console.log(request.body);
  const Company = request.Company;
  const Position = request.Position;
  const Email = request.Email;
  const NumberOfEmployees = request.NumberOfEmployees;
  const Message = request.Message;
  if (!Company || !Position || !Email || !NumberOfEmployees || !Message) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'All form fields are required' }, { status: 400 });
  }

  try {
    
    await sql`
      INSERT INTO LeadForm (company, position, email, numberofemployees, message)
      VALUES (${Company}, ${Position}, ${Email}, ${NumberOfEmployees}, ${Message});
    `;

    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Form data inserted successfully into the database' }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Error while inserting form data into the database' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

I always recieve a 400 as an answer and the body is null while the console.log request on the front is running correctly with the data of the form.

I'm new to NextJS 13.2 and Node endpoint maybe it's a stupid thing but I really tried so many things to debuff this issue and couldn't make it.

Is it maybe related to the permission of the endpoints or some method I'm doing wrong?

I hope someone can help me with this issue

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In app router, you need to call jaon fucntion on request

```
export async function POST(request, response) {
  const body = request.json();
  console.log(body);
...
}
```

Checkout - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers